# Django Template: Exclude request.user from displaying user list

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a simple problem. Below html code return list of all users whose liked blog. How can i exclude request user from list of them ?

```
   <div class="collapse" id="likes">
     <ul>
        {% for like  in instance.likes.all  %}
          <li>
            {{like}}  
          </li>
        {% endfor %}  
     </ul>
   </div>
```

I tried as : `{{like |request.user}}` or something like this ,but no result. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the `Like` model. It has a field named `user` attached to it?

Comment: In model ,likes related to auth users likes        = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True ,related_name='post_likes')

Comment: But i don't want to filter it in model . I want filtered it in template

Comment: filtering in the model would be wrong, but in the template is actually wrong as well. This should be handled in the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably using an `{% if ... %}` to filter out that particular user:

```
<div class="collapse" id="likes">
    <ul>
        {% for like  in instance.likes.all  %}
        {% if like != request.user %}
        <li>
            {{like}}  
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}  
    </ul>
</div>
```